# most frequently occurring string (element) in a list?

Tags: string, list, haskell

I have made a function which prints every possible subsequence of a string. Now I need to make a function which prints the most common. Any ideas on where I can start. Not asking for fully coded functions just a place to start. Also, only using prelude functions (including base).

for example, if I enter `"jonjo"` my functions will return `["jonjo","jonj","jon","jo","j","onjo","onj"...]` etc. The most common substring would be `"jo"`.

In the case where there would be two or more most occurring substrings, only the longest would be printed. If still equal, any one of the substrings will suffice.

Comment: Well the most common substring for every string is the empty string... You should be more specific.

Comment: how about 'abcabc' ? Which one is most common? 'abc'? Or 'ab'? Or 'bc'? Or just 'a'?

Comment: Just updated to answer this.

Comment: You are making many edits to your question, but you are not fixing the core problem of your question.

Answer (score 5):

The problem as it is stated can be reduced to finding the most frequent character, since it is obvious that, for example, the first character in any "most frequent substring" will be AT LEAST as frequent as the substring itself.

Comment: Although I wholeheartedly agree with this what you wrote (the problem is not well stated at all)... shouldn't this be a comment on the OP's question? You're basically asking for clarification, here.

Comment: @Jubobs It depends.. It could be an acceptable answer, if the problem is just overcomplicated.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you take a look at

```
sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
```

from base Data.List

```
group :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
```

from base Data.List

```
length :: [a] -> Int
```

from base Prelude, base Data.List

and

```
maximum :: Ord a => [a] -> a
```

from base Prelude, base Data.List

If you can really ony use prelude functions, then I suggest you implement these yourself, or design a datastructure to make this efficient, such as a trie.